# Freeform: select input required

Tags: solspace-freeform

I've never been able to get the required parameter to work with a select input. Any ideas why?

```
            {exp:freeform:form
                ...
             required="full_name|email|organization|telephone|country"
                ...
                }
```

Then the input code as follows:

```
<select id="countries" name="country[]"  required>
<option value="">Please select</option>
...
```

Comment: Why have you got an array for the country value if this is an address?  I'm fairly certain Freeform can't handle arrays.  Does `name="country"` work?

Comment: I think Freeform does handle arrays. But the array wasn't needed as you state, and this caused the validation to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "required=" parameter.
https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#required